# Event when CSS is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

At a certain stage, I am applying CSS to a section of my page.
Is there an event one can get once the re-layout has completed?

Comment: We're not in the 90s, css applies almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and trigger custom events:

Binding the custom event:

```
$("#section").bind("layoutchange", function() {
    // stuff to do when the layout changes
});
```

Triggering the custom event:

```
$("#secton").css({propertyX: otherValue }).trigger("layoutchange");
```

However, this custom "layoutchange" event is not related to the actual reflow being completed, but one can assume that the reflow is fast enough, so that by the time you execute the handler it has been completed.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that will have to do.